# Trying to determine the number of users that created an entry for a particular period of days after registering in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to determine the count of users that saved a place in our database within a certain period of time after registering (a few different periods, within 7 days, 14 days, 30, etc). I can do the following:

```
SELECT "Users".email FROM "Users"
  LEFT JOIN "UserPlaces" ON "Users".id = "UserPlaces"."UserId"
WHERE "Users"."createdAt"::date = '2015-01-11'
  AND "UserPlaces"."createdAt"::date BETWEEN '2015-01-11' AND '2015-01-25'
GROUP BY "Users".email
```

This gives me a list of emails which I can count, but this isn't particularly helpful as I need to constantly change the dates. I like to be able to query the count of users that match a certain time frame parameter of adding a place after registering, ie. how many users added a place 7 days after registering

Answer (score 0):

You can just use date arithmetic, if I understand the question correctly:

```
SELECT "Users".email
FROM "Users" u INNER JOIN
     "UserPlaces" p
     ON u.id = p."UserId" AND
        p."createdAt"::date BETWEEN u."createdAt"::date AND
                                    u."createdAt"::date + 14 * interval '1 day'
WHERE u."createdAt"::date = '2015-01-11'
GROUP BY u.email;
```

The condition on dates should be in the `on` clause.  Otherwise, the `left join` would turn into an `inner join`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your super quick reply! Was trying to figure this out on my own after you responded, and the query makes total sense, but for some reason it's only returning the emails that registered on that particular date. What I like to get is what users were active after they registered for various time periods. I hope that's clear

Comment: @vivekmgeorge . . . Perhaps you don't really want the condition `where u."createdAt"::date = '2015-01-11'`.

Comment: I tried that as well before replying (should of mentioned that). Every time it returns the exact same number of emails, whether I change the number of days from 1 to 100..

Comment: @vivekmgeorge . . . If I had to guess, there is a `UserPlaces` record created when the `User` record is created.

Comment: Nope. Check that too. This is what I have now: https://gist.github.com/vivekmgeorge/5f85dc2e3bbc79c0de63 Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Gordon! I couldn't get it last week so I time boxed it and returned to it today. Finally got it! This is what I did https://gist.github.com/vivekmgeorge/695d1633361fe2d6e72a. This blog post helped me http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/. Thanks for point me in the right direction initially!